# WPF DependencyProperty for class that inherits from List(Of T)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a control that is inheriting another third party control to extend some base functionality.  As a result of this, I can't also inherit DependencyObject.

I set up an attached DependencyProperty via the follow manner on my AerosWpfMap control:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property CountyCodesProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CountyCodes", GetType(SystemCountyCodes), GetType(AerosWpfMap), New FrameworkPropertyMetaData(Nothing))
```

And the Property is defined as follows:

```
Public Property CountyCodes As SystemCountyCodes
        Get
            Return Dispatcher.Invoke(Function()
                                         Return GetValue(CountyCodesProperty)
                                     End Function)
        End Get
        Set
            SetValue(CountyCodesProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
```

The tricky part here is that the SystemCountyCodes class inherits a List(Of CountyCodeInfo).

Now, I have a window class called UI that contains this AerosWpfMap control and I am trying to bind the CountyCodes property of the AerosWpfMap to the CountyCodes property in my UI class.  I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged in my window and raise the event during the setter of the CountyCodes property as indicated below:

```
Public Property CountyCodes As SystemCountyCodes
        Get
            Return _countyCodes
        End Get
        Set
            _countyCodes = value
            RaiseEvent INotifyPropertyChanged_PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("CountyCodes"))
        End Set
    End Property
```

And the binding in my Xaml of the UI.xaml is as follow:

```
<mapping:AerosWpfMap x:Name="Map" 
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Background="{StaticResource CheckerBackground}"
                         CountyCodes="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mapping:UI}}, Path=CountyCodes, Mode=OneWay}"
                         Srid="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mapping:UI}}, Path=Srid, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Ironically enough, it doesn't appear to work unless I specify the relative source that way, even though I should be able to use RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}.

This all works and binds fine when it runs; however, I am still presented with the following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'CountyCodes' property of type 'Controls_Mapping_AerosWpfMap_17_362199327'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject. AerosAdjusterMapping    C:\Projects\AerosAdjusterMapping\AerosAdjusterMapping\Controls\Mapping\UI.xaml  383

This leads me to believe I still have something set up incorrectly.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I think I may either have the concept of the DependencyProperty backwards (i.e. it should be on the target (UI) and not the Source(AerosWpfMap), or that I need to have my AerosWpfMap control inherit from a DependencyObject, but as I stated, since it already inherits from another control I cannot go this route.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and apologies for it being in VB (it is one of the requirements for this).  I am fluent in C# as well so any help in either language would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The third party control that your AerosWpfMap derives from seems to be already derived from DependencyObject, otherwise you couldn't call its GetValue and SetValue methods. So you should be able to declare your property as a regular dependency property, not as an attached property. Besides that, you must not call Dispatcher.Invoke in the property getter.

Comment: I had to call that because the value was getting loaded via an Async call in another class.  If I didn't invoke, I would receive an error that I cannot access it on the thread it wasn't created on or something of that nature.

Let me give it a try as a regular dependency property and see if that helps alleviate the xaml errors.

Comment: Instead of that, you should call the property getter in an Invoke action. The CLR wrapper of a dependency property must not call anything else than GetValue and SetValue.

Comment: Okay, pardon my ignorance here, but is not the call I did above to retrieve the value logically equivalent in terms of functionality?

Comment: From what you've shown it isn't very clear which property you are actually binding. Is that binding on the CountyCodes property of a AerosWpfMap element in the UI's XAML? You may probably show a bit more of your XAML.

Comment: Okay, I included the full map declaration in the Xaml for the UI.xaml so it is more clear.  Thanks.